# Windows 11 how to highlight focused window in system tray

Tags: windows-11, user-interface

When you hover an application which has multiple windows open in the system tray, previous versions of Windows showed a visual difference in the previews which pop up, for the window which has focus.

Is there any way to bring back this behavior?

I've tried searching through the personalization settings, but found nothing related.